# Div Id is missing from source code although is present in browser

Tags: jquery

I have this script that redirects page if new div id is received from another page :

page#1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$('#result').load('logged.html #intro');
});

if ($("#intro").length > 0){
window.location.href = "logged.html";
}
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

div from page#2

```
<div id="intro">Hi, this is the Intro!</div>
```

I receive the correct message on page#1, if I inspect element its there but if open source code of the page new div is missing. Why is that ? I need it there in order to trigger event based on his presence.

Comment: If you are user browser dev tools,hit refresh and the dynamic elements usually appear. If you are not using dev tools, you should be. When I say refresh, I mean for the dev tools, not the page, fyi.

Comment: If you are using web developer extension then you can find in the `view generated source` in firefox.

Answer (score 4):

The source of any page will be the original file sent by the server. If you modify the DOM, these changes will *not* appear in the source.

Comment: they will appear in the developers tools tho